# bug with 'unique'? Don't get an error when 'nmax' is 1 less than the number of unique values

Tags: r, vector, unique

Have tested this on R 3.5.0.

```
set.seed(0)
x <- rexp(100)
length(unique(x))  ## 100

## this fails as I expect
unique(x, nmax = 98)
#Error in unique.default(x, nmax = 98) : hash table is full

## but how come does this succeed?
length(unique(x, nmax = 99))  ## 100
```

Comment: Same behavior with function `duplicated`.

Comment: Why wrap only the second call in `length`? I think this would be more clear if you used `length` in both or neither case of calling unique with nmax of 98 & 99

Comment: @Anonymouscoward Thanks. Now `factor` has the same problem.

Comment: I guess anything that calls `duplicated` has the problem.

Comment: Well, to quote P Dalgaard in that linked thread, "nmax is directly linked to a variable in C code, and I expect that 0-based indexing is the reason that nmax can be one less than the actual number of unique values." which was sort of my hunch, it does seem like odd behavior.